# RouteProvider not changing template in ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the templates to change without refreshing the page. I'm not sure what's wrong with the code since the console is blank until I click Page 1 or Page 2 Link
then I get this error in console. http://pastebin.com/J3Y5NauN
It should just view the template in div ng-view without refreshing.
app.js, index.html, page1.html, and page2.html are all in the same directory also.
Any ideas?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Angular Test</title>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
{{"Hello"}}
<br>
<br>

<a ng-href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
<a ng-href="page2.html">Page 2</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="bower_components/bower-angularjs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('page1.html', {
templateUrl: 'newtest/page1.html'


})
.when('page2.html', {
templateUrl: 'page2.html'

});
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase:false});

}]);
```

page1.html

This is Page 1

page2.html

This is Page 2

Comment: Can't run this from file system...page needs to load from a server in order for ajax to work. Install a localhost server on your computer

Comment: I didn't realize I was using ajax. Can you point out which code is ajax because I thought it was all angular and I could run it locally without a server

Comment: angular uses ajax to load templates unless you include them in script tags. but since you have bower then you are using node and can open a node server

Comment: I just got it setup on a http://localhost:8080, but it just jumps to http://localhost:8080/page1 or http://localhost:8080/page2. Also nothing ever renders under Hello where the div ng-view is. It should be rendering This is Page 1 or This is Page 2, but it stays blank under the word Hello. Also the console doesn't throw errors now onclick with Page1 or Page2 hyperlinks.

Comment: Will also need to configure server for html5mode. Not good strategy using file name for routing either

Comment: If it's not a good strategy can you show me an example of a better way of doing this?

Comment: Lots of answers in google but basically need server to always route to app entry point. Can add `#/page.html` in href for now and turn off html5mode just to test